# Derivative of $f(x)=0$ at $x=0$ using the limit definition

Tags: limits, derivatives

I suddenly came across something so rudimentary I'm a little lost as to how to calculate the definition based on the definition of a limit.

How do you go from here to get to the fact that the derivative is 0?
Why is this $\frac{0}{0}$ here not considered an indeterminate form?

$$ f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{0-0}{h}$$

Is it just that you multiply the numerator by $h$, and then cancel out the $h$'s?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{0}{h}=0$.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as I typed this question I realized that h is approaching zero, and not actually zero.

Comment: @Snowball The fact that $h$ approaches zero instead of being zero is not the relevant issue here (because there are cases where this happens but the limit is not zero (even if the numerator goes to zero)). You have to compute $0/h$ before taking the limit, otherwise you get the indeterminate form $0/0$. See my answer below. You can multiply by $h$ provided that the simplification is done before taking the limit (but I think it is easier to remember that zero divided by anything except zero is zero).

Comment: Thanks for that extra clarification!

Answer (score 2):

If $c$ is constant with respect to $h$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}c=c.$$

Usin this with $c=0$, we obtain:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{h}= \lim_{h\rightarrow0} 0=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(0) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \displaystyle  {\frac {f(h) - f (0)}{h}} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \displaystyle {\frac {0-0}{h}}$$ . Now numarator of thefraction is 0 denominator is going towards 0 not equals 0... hence denominator has a value other than 0..so any fraction with numarator 0 and denominator non zero real number is 0. Limit of the denominator is 0 not equals to 0

Comment: Your last equality is not correct. After removing $\lim$, the $h$ have to disappear too.